# How to take screenshot of file's content using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

In google drive, you are able to see a preview of each file's content: [Google Drive Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e52pK.jpg)

I was wondering if I could use nodejs to replicate this feature.
I tried looking for node modules but couldn't find any.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far? If you are looking for library suggestions, this board may not be suitable for that. Anyway, check if this one serves you in this purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-thumbnail

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues that module only creates thumbnails of image file. I need to create thumbnails for other files as well such as word documents, pdf, etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `I don’t want to connect to Google Drive.`, I could understand that my answer was not suitable for your goal. But unfortunately, I cannot propose the method for retrieving the thumbnail of files on Google Drive without using Drive API. So I have to delete my answer because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.